# Как с помощью кнопки и цикла выводить новую информацию в UILabel?

Tags: objective-c

Есть общий класс Animal и потомки (еще три класса), которые содержат имя, возраст, цвет животного. Еще есть кнопка вперед при нажатии на которую должна меняться информация. Знает ли кто как это можно сделать.
Класс Animal:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OMAnimal : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *color;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger age;

@end
```

Отображение:

```
#import "OMAnimalViewController.h"
#import "OMCat.h"
#import "OMDog.h"
#import "OMMonkey.h"

@interface OMAnimalViewController ()

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *arrayAnimal;

@end

@implementation OMAnimalViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

OMCat *animalCat = [[OMCat alloc] init];

animalCat.name = @"Kate";
animalCat.age = 6;
animalCat.color = @"White";

OMDog *animalDog = [[OMDog alloc] init];

animalDog.name = @"Bob";
animalDog.age = 3;
animalDog.color = @"Balck";

OMMonkey *animalMonkey = [[OMMonkey alloc] init];

animalMonkey.name = @"Charly";
animalMonkey.age = 7;
animalMonkey.color = @"Brown";

_arrayAnimal = @[animalCat, animalDog, animalMonkey];

[self updateAnimal];
}

- (void)updateAnimal {

OMCat *cat = _arrayAnimal[0];

self.nameLabel.text = cat.name;
self.ageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", cat.age];
self.colorLabel.text = cat.color;

}

- (IBAction)actionNext:(UIButton *)sender {

}

@end
```

Comment: как то можно конкретнее. где и в каком формате хранится информация? как узнать что на экране сейчас? в каком формате надо вывести новую информацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не проверял, но вроде должно работать.

```
- (void)updateAnimal {

    OMAnimal *current = self.arrayAnimal[self.index];

    self.nameLabel.text = current.name;
    self.ageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", current.age];
    self.colorLabel.text = current.color;
}

- (IBAction)actionNext:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.index = (self.index+1) % self.arrayAnimal.count;
    [self updateAnimal];
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.) Все работает отлично.  Если не трудно можете объяснить следующее выражение: self.index = (self.index+1) % self.arrayAnimal.count.

Comment: Это такой сильно умный способ прибавлять 1 к индексу без переполнения. Каждый раз после прибавления 1 к индексу он делится на количество элементов в массиве и присваивается остаток. То есть если например у вас 3 элемента в массиве, если после прибавления 1 к индексу он становится 1 или 2, то все нормально, а если он становится 3 то остаток от деления будет 0. Если твуой вариант сложно читать то можете вместо этого написать `self.index++; if(self.index == self.arrayAnimal.count) self.index = 0;`

Comment: и не забудьте принять ответ, если все работает

Comment: Ответ Принят..)

Comment: что то мне не показывает что принят